# bugged HTML code editor

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     
     var btn = $('.gen');
     btn.on('click', function() {
      var areaTxt = $('.textarea').val();
      var div = $('.result');
      div.html(areaTxt);
     });
     
    });
```

```css
.result {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    }
    .textarea {
     width: 300px;
     height: 150px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>  
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="gen" value="generate">
    <div class="result"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've created a simple HTML code editor. The problem is that when I add style for all classes or divs affect also to my code editor.

I want something like the editor of w3school. Just to show the result in iframe but all code in the textarea to affect only the result area.

http://jsfiddle.net/sederther/4x6dxrs5/

Comment: Than you need to use an iframe like they do.

Comment: yes but they also use external iframe...i think that they also use external html page, i need help

Comment: can you create fiddle please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check fiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4x6dxrs5/3/)

Just did a few tweaking. Added a dummy attribute to 'textarea' and set a value for that attribute. I then loop through the element and check for the attribute, if found I will reset all the styles applied.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var btn = $('.gen');
        btn.on('click', function() {
            var areaTxt = $('.textarea').val();
            var div = $('.result');
            div.html(areaTxt);



            //Code Addtion
            $("textarea").each(function(){
                var attr = 
                $(this).attr('dataref');
                if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false && attr == 'source') {

$(this).attr('style', 'background-color: #eee !important');

}
            })
        });

    });
```

In this case, I am looping all the 'textareas' and check if it has 'dataref' attribute and the value equals source. if so then reset its style. I know it would be tedious to work on all the elements in similar manner, but without using iframe this can be work around.

my 2 cents

Comment: Yeah it works in this case, but when i set for example background-color to red for all div elements everything mess up.

Comment: You can similarly set the dummy attribute for a div and make the JavaScript more generic.let me know if you need any help..I can help you by updating the fiddle

Comment: this is noo solution, check my fiddle and in the textarea type '<div style="background: red; width: 300px; height: 450;"></div>' and see what happening with my result div.

Comment: @DavidPankov I changed the style from 'background' to 'background-color' and 'height' to '450px'. the 'px' in 'height' was missing, also the '-color' in background was missing. with this changes it worked fine. '<div style="background-color:red; width: 300px; height:450px;"></div>'. could you please check this now

Comment: my real code Editor is not only for HTML, and there are lots of elements, like input, span, div, textarea, img, a and so on. So i dont want when someone change the style for all <a> link to change the styls of my code editor. That's why i need exactly result in iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your styles specifically for the box of results would not solve your problem?

```
.result p {
    font-size:8px;
    font-family:Georgia;
}
.result h1{
    color:red;
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:Georgia;
}
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4x6dxrs5/2/

Comment: This is not what i want. I want free coding. Like code editor.

Comment: Is that not what he suggested? I think you need to clarify what you want